# Looping through a file Python

Tags: python, json, sqlite

I must not be doing something right in my loop. The below is collecting the first line for the file and adding it to the db correctly. However, it is not going to the second, third, etc.

```
#Open file
webFD=urllib2.urlopen("file")
tweet = webFD.readline()


#create dictionary
dictt=json.loads(tweet)

#add lines to db
for elt in tweet:
    currentRow = elt[:+1]
c.execute('INSERT INTO Tweet VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
        (dictt['created_at'], dictt["id"], dictt["text"], dictt['source'], dictt['in_reply_to_user_id'],dictt['retweet_count']))
conn.commit()
```

Comment: You never use the variable currentRow, and also your insertion statement is outside the for loop.

Comment: @kevinsa5. Thanks. Not to be remedial, but what would i use in its place?

Comment: You need to iterate over the file. Right now, you open the file, read a single line from it, make a dict from it, do a loop (that doesn't do anything, it creates a variable that's never used), then do a single insertion and commit. What you need to do is open the file, then straightaway enter the loop, create a dict for each line in the file, insert it, then exit the loop and commit.

Comment: @kevinsa5 still stuck on this. I get what you are saying, but can seem to code it. Could I ask you a deep favor and type out the code for what you are saying. I must be missing something. Thanks so much.

Comment: The comment box is no good for code, see the answer I posted. Let me know if that's not what you meant.

Comment: @kevinsa5 I am getting JSON error with that. I am going back up to post the entire thing, as a "new answer".

Comment: @kevinsa5- just posted by "bad" loop as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are not looping through the file at all. The file that you're loading contains many different JSON objects, and you have to loop through them. Without a loop, of course it will only do a single entry. Also, you should have said that this was homework. Here is the pseudocode:

```
import various libraries
initialize sql database
for each line in the file, parse the line (using json.loads) into a dict
    insert the dict data into the database
commit
```

Here's another hint: Each JSON entry in the file is a single line, but looping through each line in the file will also return the blank lines. How can you deal with that?